# JAX-RS Rest endpoint with sendgrid email sender method error

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, backend, sendgrid

I'm working on a fullstack app (confluence macro), with java backend where i use jax-rs rest endpoints. I would like to fetch the email sender endpoint from javascript this way:

```
async function sendemail() {
    let response = await fetch('/rest/documentApprove/latest/connection/mail',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
    });
}
```

This is the endpoint in Java:

```
@GET
@Path("/email")
public void sendEmail() throws IOException {

    Email from = new Email("example@email.com");
    String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    Email to = new Email("example1@email.com");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("MYAPIKEY");
    Request request = new Request();
    try {
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        com.sendgrid.Response response = sg.api(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    };
}
```

When I call this endpoint i get this error message:

```xml
<status-code>500</status-code>
<message>com/sendgrid/helpers/mail/objects/Email</message>
<stack-trace>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sendgrid/helpers/mail/objects/Email
```

If I try inside a simple public static void main method the email sender part it works properly

Comment: Have you imported the SendGrid library with `import com.sendgrid.*;`?

Comment: Yes, I have these imports:                                                                                       import com.sendgrid.*;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.Mail;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Content;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.Email;

Comment: You should only need `import com.sendgrid.*`, can you remove the other imports. Also, are those imports in the same file that this `sendEmail` method is defined? Is there more code from this file that you can share?